# Can I suppress the <use [filename]> message?

Tags: graphics, compiling

When I compile something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
blabla

\includegraphics{image}

blabla
\end{document}
```

I get a `<use [filename]>` message in the log. Since I have a lot of imported images, these messages are everywhere in the log and I'd like to remove them.

Is it possible?

Comment: `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` removes the images and the messages :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The printout of file names is too deep inside TeX to be changed
by higher level macros.

The only way that would suppress the printout of file names is to create a pre-compiled  "[precompiled-preamble](http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-iv-use-a-precompiled-preamble/)". This process is the same as used for generating the `latex` command from `tex`. Command `latex` is nothing but bare bones `tex` unto which the LaTeX preamble was pre-compiled.

All inclusions made within the preamble, are not reported. Alas, pre-compiled preambles are not likely to be usable for the specific help the problem you report.

Comment: can you elaborate? What is a pre-compiled image?

Comment: Why don't you fully edit your answer?

Comment: Done! Always at your disposal --yg